# Realtime input field value change as user types

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently busy working with an `web-service` with `ajax/json`.

I am retrieving all `values`, but now I would like the user to update their details.

I would like to know, how can I change an input field's `value="?"` to the text that the user is currently typing (in real-time)?

What I do is, I populate the labels with actual data that I am retrieving using the web-service.

When you click `'Update Details'`, my `jQuery` code will change the labels to input fields, only problem now is that I would like to populate the user text as he types, grab these values and send it back to the web-service.

Here is my code. (The form)

```
<form>
        <table class="table AccountDetails">
            <tr>
                <td>Account holder:</td>
                <td><label id="AccountHolder" class="editable"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Primary email:</td>
                <td><label id="PrimaryEmail" class="editable"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact number:</td>
                <td><label id="ContactNumber" class="editable"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Terms and conditions:</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label id="TCs" class="editable"></label></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<label id="TCsDateAccepted"></label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" id="updateDetails" href="#">Update Details</a>
                </td>
                <td align="right"><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Review T&amp;C's</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

$("#updateDetails").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

```
if($this.attr('editing') != '1') {
    $this.attr('editing', 1);
    $(document).find('.editable').each(function() {
        var input = $('<input class="editing" value="'+$(this).text()+'" />');
        //input.val($(this).text());
        $(this).replaceWith(input);
        console.log( $(input).val());
    });
}
else {
    $this.removeAttr('editing');
    $(document).find('input.editing').each(function() {
        var div = $('<div class="editable" />').text($(this).val());
        console.log( $('.editing').val());
        $(this).replaceWith(div);
    });
}
```

});

I do hope I am making sense here.
Please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Why do you want to send it to the server as he types? That seems like a pointless way of wasting bandwidth. A better solution is to show a submit button when the editors are toggled on, why not show a 'Submit' button and send it to the server when that is clicked.

Comment: you would need to use like a `keydown()` function or similiar, you should give it a try first and ask a question if you're unable to get it working

Comment: I do not wish to send it to the server as he types. Sorry maybe I was a bit unclear.

All I would like to do is, update the value field of the input as the user types.

I will send this data to the server once the user clicks "Update Details" again.

Comment: @Deedz I have not clear you Question. Can you explain little bit more. What you want finally.

Comment: @yeshansachithak, I have managed to get the value field to be populated with the current text in the input. *Updated code*.

Now, when a user types something in the input field, I would like the <input value="Something here"> to be updated as he types. Say I am busy typing "Hello World", I want the "Hello World" to appear as the value when inspecting the element. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Deedz I think it's already working as you wish right. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/xtLbce60/)

Comment: @yeshansachithak, thank you so much. Yes, I actually changed my console.log() and seems to be outputting the correct data. Seems like my previous edit var input = $('<input class="editing" value="'+$(this).text()+'" />'); solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As I understand you want an input and some text to update as the input updates. This might help you:

```
var $text = $('#text');
var $input = $('#input');
$input.on('keyup', function () {
  $text.html($input.val());
});
```

And with a little trick you can make it even more responsive:

```
var $text = $('#text');
var $input = $('#input');
$input.on('keydown', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $text.html($input.val());
  }, 0); // On next loop
});
```

Here is a small fiddle: http://jsbin.com/luzidaro/1/edit

Comment: Thanks @christianalfoni, I actually managed to solve my issue. :) Thanks for the code snippet, will definitely make use of that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by replacing the following line

```
var input = $('<input class="editing" />').val($(this).text());
```

with

```
var input = $('<input class="editing" value="'+$(this).text()+'" />');
```